# Why was the DEC Q-Bus called the Q-bus?

Tags: history, pdp-11

The bus used for DEC's LSI-11 microcomputer implementation of the PDP-11 was originally and prosaically referred to as the LSI-11 bus, but thereafter it was universally referred to as the Q-bus.

Does this name have any meaning?  And if so, what was it?

Comment: Looking through the material on bitsavers, the name change from "LSI-11 bus" to "Q-bus" must have happened between 1983 and 1985, if that helps anyone else in digging up an answer.

Comment: That timeframe suggests the introduction of the MicroVAX, which is plausibly a reason for not calling it the "LSI-11 bus" any more. [The uVAX I description](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/vax/610/EK-KD32A-TD-002_MicroVAX_I_CPU_Technical_Description_Aug84.pdf) says "extended LSI-11 bus (also called Q22 bus)".

Comment: But I am still be curious why they called it "Q". But it's a good point; maybe MicroVAX docs can provide hints.

Comment: I also noticed the Q22 name, but I think that means "Q-bus with extra signals".

Comment: @dirkt - I too am still curious as to 'why'; and yes, Q22 distinguishes the variant from Q16 (=original LSI-11 bus) and Q18 (=PDP-11/23 bus).

Comment: Long-time Unix programmer Clem Cole recently wrote that Western Digital created the LSI-11 bus to avoid being sued by DEC.  Some other company had made a PDP-11 clone with Unibus; this didn't go down well with DEC laywers.  But DEC adopted the LSI-11 and the new bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [LSI-11 Bus Specification](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/standards/EL-00160-00-0_A_DEC_STD_160_LSI-11_Bus_Specification_Sep91.pdf) has a section on history and folklore, and states

> The original backplane to implement the LSI-11 Bus was designed to
>   accommodate Digital's quad and dual height modules. It became known
>   as the "Q-Bus" to reflect the quad board form factor. Both LSI-11 Bus
>   and Q-BUS are Digital trademarks, but are not registered trademarks.
>   Several bus architecture features of the LSI-11 Bus are protected by
>   claims in Digital Unibus patent numbers 3,710,324 and 3,815,099. Some
>   publications may also use the term SUB-UNIBUS, although this is not
>   recommended.
>
> When the LSI-11 Bus was expanded to provide 22 address lines, the
>   terms Q22-Bus and extended LSI-11 Bus were adopted to specify
>   backplanes [of] that bus [with] the four additional lines.

Comment: "Q" for "quad", as opposed to the usual hex-height backplanes for Unibus systems. Perfectly obvious once it has been pointed out!  Good sleuthing, there.

Comment: Clem Cole claims the Q-bus was essentially invented by Western Digital.  (Possibly no the name, though.

Comment: Source: https://minnie.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2020-January/019964.html